# Not able to turn off quarkus.micrometer

Tags: quarkus, micrometer

I’m not able to turn off  quarkus.micrometer.

I don't have the Configuration property "quarkus.micrometer.enabled" in my resource\application.property.
But have tried to overide in
config\application.properties and in .env and in environment variable and in system property. And is not able to disable quarkus.micrometer.
In my pom I include quarkus-micrometer and quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-micrometer_quarkus.micrometer.enabled), `quarkus.micrometer.enabled` is a **build time** property. That means that you can **not** change it's value at runtime.

Comment: OK so overriding a Configuration property in `config\application.properties` so that the application starts up with what is configured in `config\application.properties` does not work for `quarkus.micrometer.enabled`